# Ternary operator in an anonymous function

Tags: scala

In Scala I can do:

```
scala> (1 to 5).map( x => if (x % 2 == 0) x else "Not even number" )
res58: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any] = Vector(Not even number, 2, Not even number, 4, Not even number)
```

But I can't do:

```
(1 to 5).map( x => (x % 2 == 0) ? x : "Not even number" )
```

I get:

```
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but string literal found.
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ternary `?` operator in Scala, using `if/else` is the only way to achieve this.